# AWS Deploy to multiple ecs in CICD using CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, ecs-taskdefinition

**I want to configure the CICD using AWS CodePipeline but I want to deploy in multiple environments**. How to do that?

 Source is same, codebuild can also be same I think, please correct if I am wrong. The difference comes in deploy stage. I want to deploy to two different set of resources i:e ECS Cluster. First deployment is the staging env, I want to check all the resources and logs manually before approving it and then which deploys to Production. Is this possible and how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need to have multiple phases in the pipeline:

Source ---> Build ---> Deploy (to staging) ---> Deploy (to production)

You would add a [manual approval](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/approvals-action-add.html) action to the final deploy phase.